# Meaning of 'thread-safe' in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java

Its OK that CHM provides performance gains when used instead of Collections.synchronizedMap(...)/hashtable, due to bucket level locking.

Its also OK that when we do not want our iterator to throw ConcurrentModificationException , we use CHM.

BUT I am confused with the meaning of `thread-safe` in context of CHM as they does not prevent changes to get reflected between retrievals and writes overlappings?

Comment: "they does not prevent changes to get reflected between retrievals and writes overlapping". I can't make much sense out of that. Please reword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aix mentioned that Sharing `ConcurrentHashMap` object across multiple threads without external lock is `Thread-Safe`

How it works is like ConcurrentHashMap ( Sun's current implementation) works by dividing the underlying map into a number of separate buckets. Getting an element does not require any locking per se, but it does use atomic/volatile operations, which implies a memory barrier (potentially very costly, and interfering with other possible optimisations) but in `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)` lock is applied to whole map so it is costly.

**Usage:**
`ConcurrentHashMap is implemented for higher throughput in cases where high concurrency is expected`

Answer (score 2):

What thread safety means is that you are permitted to share a `ConcurrentHashMap` object across multiple threads, and to access/modify that object concurrently without external locking.

The exact semantics are explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including `get`) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset.
>
> For aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, `Iterators` and `Enumerations` return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.